# Cannot find pgsql.so in php.ini

Tags: php, postgresql, php-pgsql

After installed php5-pgsql on Ubuntu using the command

```
sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql
```

I couldn't find pgsql.so file in php.ini, when i do a

```
 locate pgsql.so
```

nothing returns. So anyone knows why the installation shows successful, but the module file doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to locate the file by issuing **dpkg -L**:

```
$ dpkg -L php5-pgsql | grep .so
/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pgsql.so
/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_pgsql.so
```

Also, note that **locate** command acts over a database that must be updated by previously executing **updatedb**.

Comment: it works, but when i add pgsql.so to php.ini and try to connect to database, i get an error    "Call to undefined function pg_connect()", which means the module is not installed